# Function to find overlapping lists of numbers (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an exam for a frontend developer bootcamp I'm enrolled in.

From the exam, the question states,

/* Question 03

Implement a function "checkOverlap", which, when given two objects that represent lines,
returns whether they overlap or not.

Lines are represented in this way: {start: 0, end: 10}

(end will always be greater than start)

```
Example 1:

  checkOverlap({start: 0, end: 10}, {start: 8, end: 15})

Which visually, would be:

   0--------10

         8-------15

         ^^^^ overlap

Returns:

  true


Example 2:

  checkOverlap({start: 12, end: 15}, {start: 0, end: 10})

Which visually, would be:

                 12-------15

   0--------10

                  no overlap

Returns:

  false
```

The code I've written for the function is,

```
function checkOverlap(lineA, lineB) {
  /* IMPLEMENT ME */
  let aLineArr = [];
  let bLineArr = [];

for (let ind = lineA.start; ind < lineA.end + 1; ind++) {
    aLineArr.push(ind);
  }
  for (let ind = lineB.start; ind < lineB.end + 1; ind++) {
    bLineArr.push(ind);
  }

  // Code below passes all ovelapping cases
  let overlap = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < bLineArr.length; i++) {
    if (aLineArr.indexOf(bLineArr[i]) >= 0) {
      overlap = true;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return overlap;
}
```

The conditions I have to meet in the test are defined in the following test,

```
const chai    = require("chai");
const sinon   = require("sinon");
const assert  = chai.assert;

const checkOverlap = require("../answers/03.js");

describe("checkOverlap", () => {

  describe("overlapping", () => {

    it("Sample 1", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 0, end: 10};
      var lineB = {start: 8, end: 15};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), true);
    });

    it("Sample 1 (Reversed)", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 8, end: 15};
      var lineB = {start: 0, end: 10};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), true);
    });

    it("One Inside the Other", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 0, end: 10};
      var lineB = {start: 3, end: 9};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), true);
    });

    it("One Inside the Other (Reversed)", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 3, end: 9};
      var lineB = {start: 0, end: 10};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), true);
    });

    it("Identical", () => {
      var lineA = {start: -10, end: 10};
      var lineB = {start: -10, end: 10};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), true);
    });

  });

  describe("not overlapping", () => {

    it("Sample 2", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 12, end: 15};
      var lineB = {start: 0, end: 10};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), false);
    });

    it("Sample 2 (Reversed)", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 0, end: 10};
      var lineB = {start: 12, end: 15};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), false);
    });

    it("Ends Touching", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 0, end: 10};
      var lineB = {start: 10, end: 20};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), false);
    });

    it("Ends Touching (Reversed)", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 10, end: 20};
      var lineB = {start: 0, end: 10};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), false);
    });

    it("Far Away", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 0, end: 10};
      var lineB = {start: 100, end: 200};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), false);
    });

    it("Far Away (Reversed)", () => {
      var lineA = {start: 100, end: 200};
      var lineB = {start: 0, end: 10};
      assert.equal(checkOverlap(lineA, lineB), false);
    });

  });
```

});

Currently, I've passed all tests except for TWO non-overlapping cases (1. when the Ends are touching, and 2. when the Ends are touching (reversed)...

I would like some tips/advice on solving those two non-overlapping cases!

Some help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: does same value for start and end overlap?

Comment: @NinaScholz - the "Ends Touching" touch suggests no.

Comment: so `arrA[arrA.length-1] == arrB[0]` and reverse

Comment: I just can't find it, but here in stackoverflow is a nice Answer with proof, that two intervalls a,b don't intersect exactly when the start of a is bigger than the end of b or the end of a is smaller than the start of b

Comment: I was pointing out the "overlap" to the instructor when we were writing the exam in class, but his response was something along what you've pointed out.

Something along the lines of the end of **a** goes to the **.999999** of the number, and the start of **b** actually starts on the integer of the next number.

For example:
`[1, 2, 3, 4]` ends at 3.9999999 and `[4, 5, 6]` starts at 4.

Answer (score 4):

Why create new arrays? There's much simpler solution:

```
function checkOverlap(lineA, lineB) {
    return (lineA.start >= lineB.start && lineA.start < lineB.end) || (lineB.start >= lineA.start && lineB.start < lineA.end);
}
```

EDIT:

as per suggestion in the comment, it can be even simpler:

```
function checkOverlap(lineA, lineB) {
    return (lineA.start < lineB.end) && (lineB.start < lineA.end);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, too when I was typing the question...

I'm pretty new to JS and this bootcamp is moving at a very fast pace, so I feel like I'm still getting used to things, but I do see the logic, and am doing some testing, now.

Thanks.

Comment: It can be made even more simple, see my comment to the question

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone!
I've got it working, now! :)